# Why does `img` inside `div` messes with the layout?

Tags: html, css

I am having a number of `div` elements with dimensions carefully chosen so as to fit snugly with the default (`static`) positioning within a container:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     #container {
       box-sizing: content-box;
       border: 10px solid black;
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px; 
       background: gray;
       padding: 0;
       font-size:0; /* https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ */
     }
     .cell {
       box-sizing: border-box;
       border: 10px solid green ;
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
       background: black;
       position: static;
       display: inline-block;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='container'>
      <div class='cell'>
      </div>
      <div class='cell'>
      </div>
      <div class='cell'>
      </div>
      <div class='cell'>
      </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The expected result appears in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49kvc3kx/1/).

So this is all fine and well.
However, when I attempt to add an `img` element inside a `div`:

```
  <div class='cell'>
    <img src='foobar.png'/>
  </div>
```

… the layout messes up as shown in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1ek19x1/2/).
**Note**: not finding the `src` of the image and not rendering it does not concern me. It's the layout problem that I am asking about.

The only way I discovered how to fix it is to instead place the `div` inside yet annother `div` element:

```
  <div class='cell'>
    <div class='innerCell'>
        <img src='foobar.png'/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The repaired layout in shown [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f2twgL7/1/)

My questions are:

1. What caused the mess up ?
2. Why the inner `div` fixed it ?
3. Is there a better fix ?

Comment: vertical-align: top;
in the div will solve the problem